# Is it possible to import a function as a class method?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if this is even possible.

Let's say, there are two files.

in a.py:

```
class A()
```

in b.py:

```
def x():  
def y():
```

I'd like to import a function x() from b.py to a.py's class A so that the class A has a method x.

so that i can use like this

```
test = A()
test.x()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not with that signature.

Comment: `import b ; class A(): x = staticmethod(b.x)` like that?

Comment: Seems like an XY Problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: you could create a class in b.py and inherit

Comment: Is it at all possible you are trying to import `random.shuffle` for a list subclass?  I describe why that specific case doesn't work in my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404588/python-how-to-monkey-patch-class-method-to-other-class-method/36405018#36405018)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the functions signature doesn't allow for an instance of `A` to be passed as the first argument the best you can do is make them `staticmethod`s:

```
import b
class A:
    x = staticmethod(b.x)
    y = staticmethod(b.y)

test = A()
test.x()
```

However if you had functions that could take an `A` instance as the first argument then it would just be:

```
class A:
    from b import x,y

test = A()
test.x()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try it?

**a.py**

```
class A():
    from b import x, y

a = A()
a.x()
```

**b.py**

```
def x():
    print "Hi, I'm x!"


def y():
    print "Hi, I'm y!"
```

Yikes, that didn't work!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 6, in <module>
    a.x()
TypeError: x() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

But that's simple enough to fix, methods expect a class instance to be passed to them! Let's just modify **b.py**...

**b.py**, modified

```
def x(self):
    print "Hi, I'm x!"


def y(self):
    print "Hi, I'm y!"
```

Executing this will print:

> Hi, I'm x!

Remember to try before you post - often the answer is as simple as "Yes, just do it!" :)

Comment: you may want to clarify "class methods expect a class instance" since [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) is a real thing that has nothing to do with this case, maybe just say "methods expect an instance of the class"  (other then that; really good answer!)